# Utilizar mailgun en producción

Tags: laravel

Mi problema es que en Localhost, en mi proyecto laravel, puedo enviar mails con mailgun, pero a la hora de pasarlo a producción esto deja de funcionar y me arroja el siguiente error:

"Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailgun.org :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp.mailgun.org:21 (Connection timed out)"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*PD: Hace unas horas subí un posteo parecido, pero eran errores diferentes. El otro se encargaba de otro problema*

Comment: Algo esta bloqueando ese puerto, muchas veces los hosts o servidores ya tienen mails incluidos y puertos configurados, porque no usas uno de esos si esta disponible

Comment: Bien, como puedo saber cuales están disponibles? O que es lo que tengo que hacer para que pueda mandar mails?

Comment: eso depende de cada servidor, si es linux debes verificar los puertos mediante consola, todo depende del tipo de servidor

Comment: Lo único que encuentro en mi servidor es puerto:21, pero cuando en el ENV cambio el puerto a 21, sigue sin funcionar... que otra cosa puedo hacer?

Comment: Entonces el servidor esta bloqueando la conexion, no se si tengas manera de configurar el firewall o algo que bloquee conexiones salientes que no esten registradas